# xml to json transformation Spring/Java

Tags: java, json, xml, spring

I am looking for "transforming" (not plain-converting) XML(one data format) to JSON (to other/diff data format). Is there any tool/lib/framework to achieve this in Spring or Java?

Example
Input:

```
<root>
  <element1>abc</element1>
  <element2>xyz</element2>
.....
</root>
```

Output

```
{
"regionCode":"abc",
"regionName":"xyz"
...............
}
```

Thanks
Bharath

Answer (score 0):

Please consider searching for your question. Have you considered camel? http://camel.apache.org/xmljson.html

Comment: Hi, I already checked xmljson, it is just a plain converter from xml to json which I am not looking for. Am looking for a transformation/mapping tool like XSLT which converts one form of xml to other forms. Same way we have JOLT for JSON to JSON transformation. Is there any tool to directly do from XML to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between "transform" and "convert"?  Regardless, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) can read/write both JSON and XML (using the [XML extension](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml)). You'll have to deserialize your XML into objects before serializing them as JSON but that's not a bad thing - it would be difficult to go directly from XML to JSON except in the most simple cases (JSON does not have attributes, for example).